# Warning: The label [number] is never explicitly referenced

Tags: java, warnings

```
boolean t = true;
first:
{
    second:
    {
        third:
        {
            System.out.println("Before the break");
            if (t) {
                break second;
            }
            System.out.println("This wont execute");
        }
        System.out.println("Neither this one");
    }
    System.out.println("this will execute");

}
```

In the code, before "first" and before "third" there shows a warning: The label first/third  is never explicitly referenced.
Can ypu tell why is this warning showing?

Comment: @azurefrog: try again. "The **LABEL** ... is never..."

Comment: If you don't want to see warnings about unused code, you can generally turn them off.  For instance, in eclipse it is in Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings, in the Unnecessary code section under "Unused 'break' or 'continue' label"

Comment: What's unclear about the warning? You aren't ever using (referencing) those labels. You get a warning because since you aren't using them, they're useless and not needed.

Answer (score 3):

that is just because you are never referring them in your code

as you referred `second` by following

```
if(t) break second;
```

Answer (score -1):

### Warning: Never explicitly reference

> First of all this warning shows because of the label is never explicitly referenced. Though there is no role of that label, you still using the label in your code. and the main problem is here that the label will never closed. So, if you want to turn off the warning then you use 'break' statement.

```
    Boolean t = true;

    first:
    {

        second:
        {
            third:
            {
                System.out.println("Before the break statement.");

                if(t)
                {
                    break second;
                }
                System.out.println("This won't execute.");
                break third;
            }
            System.out.println("This won't execute.");
        }

        System.out.println("This is after second block.");
        break first;
    }
```